# using custom hook make re-render every time

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I create a custom hook take redux variable **isLoading**, can change **isLoading** true or false. I import useLoading hook in my component. But when trigger dispatch, my component always re-render and i don't understand why.
My demo is very easy here https://codesandbox.io/s/use-custom-hook-loading-oqn8e .
Can you explain me why my component always re-render and suggest me to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue:

Basically the react framework can render the component nearly *any* number of times during the render phase to compute a diff to see what needs to be flushed to the DOM during the commit phase. Your console log is in the function body, so it is executed each time react is computing this diff.

[image]

> "Render phase" ...May be paused, aborted, or ***restarted*** by React.

## Solution:

Try using an effect to log anything as it is guaranteed to run ***once*** per render cycle (render + commit). Here you'll see only a single log per update/call to `setLoading`.

```
function Main() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Main re-render");
  })
  const [, setLoading] = useLoading();
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Main</h3>
      <button onClick={() => setLoading(true)}>Start Loading</button>
      <button onClick={() => setLoading(false)}>End Loading</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The component is rerendering because its state and context are updating. This component rerenders quickly and React still diffs against the DOM to only write what's changed, so it's not an issue.

Additionally, you shouldn't copy Redux store state to React state like this, it's likely that the `loading` state in `useLoading` will become out of date. Instead, use `useSelector` directly without `useState` and just dispatch the event to set it. https://codesandbox.io/s/use-custom-hook-loading-w4pc0?file=/src/hooks/loading.js

Comment: thank for your answer, when i use useDispatch current in Main Component, it's not render anymore